# Python subprocess: stderr only saving the first line. Why?

Tags: python, process, subprocess, tcpdump

I am running `tcpdump` from within **Python** and I would like to know how many **packets** are **dropped by the kernel**.

When run on a command line, tcpdump looks like this:

```
me@mypc:$ sudo tcpdump -w myPackets.cap -i eth0 ip
tcpdump: listening on eth2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
^C28 packets captured
28 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

This is how I call `tcpdump` in my Python script:

```
f_out = open("tcpdumpSTDOUT", "w")
f_err = open("tcpdumpSTDERR", "w")
tcpdumpProcess = subprocess.Popen(['tcpdump',
                        '-w', 'myPackets.cap', '-i', 'eth0', '-n','ip'],
                        stdout=f_out,
                        stderr=f_err)
# a few seconds later:
tcpdumpProcess.kill()
f_in.close()
f_out.close()
```

Now, if I look at `tcpdumpSTDERR`, I **only** see the **first of the usual output lines**:

> tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size
>   65535 bytes

Where's all the rest?

**EDIT**
I tried a different approach:

```
>>> myProcess = subprocess.Popen("tcpdump -w myPackets.cap -i eth2 ip",  shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> myProcess.communicate()
```

Then I killed tcpdump from a different shell, and the output of commnunicate() was displayed:

```
('', 'tcpdump: listening on eth2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes\n')
```

... still the first line only!

**EDIT 2** 
Interestingly:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> a = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("tcpdump -w myPackets.cap -i eth2 ip"),  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> a.terminate()
>>> a.communicate()
('', 'tcpdump: listening on eth2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes\n221 packets captured\n221 packets received by filter\n0 packets dropped by kernel\n')
```

Comment: absolutely nothing. It's empty

Comment: Have you tried output redirection within the `subprocess` call? i.e. `tcpdump ... > tcpdumpSTDOUT`

Comment: Hmm... how exactly? Could you give me an example? thanks :)

Comment: I just did. Think about how you would do I/O redirection on the shell and do that exactly in your `subprocess` call. So on the shell, when you call `tcpdump -w myPackets.cap -i eth0 ip`. Actually, re-reading your post now, I see that `sudo` is not part of your call in `subprocess`. Are you running the python script as root?

Comment: Yes, I am already root when I run the script. I didn't get what you are saying, though. I thought that redirection was happening already when I called `subprocess.Popen()` with the parameters `stdout=f_out` and `std_err=f_err`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Yes, that /should/ happen. However, it seems to not be happening. This is why I suggest `subprocess.check_call("tcpdump -w myPackets.cap -i eth0 ip &> path/to/file", shell=True)`. This way, you'll know for sure whether the problem is with tcpdump or some quirk in the way `subprocess.Popen` is being used

Comment: When I run the above line and then kill tcpdump with `ctrl+C`, the text output is written on screen and the file where redirection was supposed to happen remains empty.

Comment: Hmm.. you might need to spawn a thread, call `subprocess.Popen` in that thread and send it a `^C` from your parent process after some time. Then, open `sys.stdout`, seek to 0 and read. This a very dirty hack, so I'd recommend a cleaner approach if you have one (sadly, I'm not able to think of one at the moment)

Comment: In the end the only problem was that I was doing `.kill()` on the process instead of `.terminate()`. My fault!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I called `kill()` on the process instead of `terminate()`. With the latter, all messages get stored in whatever I specified as `stderr` (tcpdump, for some reason, writes to stderr and not to stdout).

So, in case it might help others, I decided to redirect stderr to `subprocess.PIPE` and parse the string directly in Python:

```
>>> tcpdumpProcess = subprocess.Popen(['tcpdump',
                        '-w', 'myPackets.cap', '-i', 'eth0', '-n','ip'],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> tcpdumpProcess.terminate()
# stdout in [0], stderr in [1]
>>> tcpdump_stderr = tcpdumpProcess.communicate()[1]
>>> print tcpdump_stderr
tcpdump: listening on eth2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
40 packets captured
40 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `proc.terminate()` instead of `proc.kill()`:

```
import shlex
import subprocess
import time

with open("tcpdumpSTDERR", "wb") as f_err: # close the file automatically
    proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("tcpdump -w myPackets.cap -i eth2 ip"),
                            stderr=f_err)
time.sleep(2)    # wait a few seconds
proc.terminate() # send SIGTERM instead of SIGKILL
proc.wait()      # avoid zombies
```

Comment: You preceded me by 39 seconds :) One thing: why should SIGTERM generate zombies? I thought that only SIGKILL could.

Comment: @RickyRobinson: the signal doesn't matter. You should call `proc.wait()` even if the process finishes by itself without any external signals.